# how can i get the rendered template, with the dynamic parameters embedded, from Sendgrid response?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I'm using SendGrid API v3 with Node.js
I send emails thru the API, with my custom templates and dynamic parameters embedded.
I want to get the email HTML content from SendGrid as a result, with the parameters I passed, so I can save it.
how can I do this?